# Rails - Using form_for and fields_for, how do you access the sub-object while in the fields_for block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-forms

In my first rails app I'm trying to use `form_for` and `fields_for` to create a nested object form. So far so good, but I can't figure out how to access the sub-object while in the `fields_for` block. I've pre-populated a field in the sub-object with data that I want to show in the user instructions.

**Models**
  *Garage:*

```
has_many :cars, :dependent => :destroy         
accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars
```

*Car:*

```
belongs_to :garage
```

**Garage Controller**

```
def new
  @garage = Garage.new
  for i in 1..5 
    @garage.cars.build :stall_number => i
  end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @garage do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title, "Garage Name" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <% f.fields_for :cars do |builder| %>
    <p>Enter license for car parked in stall: <%= car.stall_number %></p>
    <%= f.label :license, "License #:" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :license %>
  <%= end %>
<%= end %>
```

As you can see, inside the builder block for :cars, I want to show, in my user instructions, the field: `car.stall_number` (populated in my controller with an integer):

```
<p>Enter license for car parked in stall: <%= car.stall_number%></p>
```

I've tried a many different ideas: `@car.stall_number`, `object.car.stall_number`, etc.  No joy. Multiple searches and a look at the `fields_for` source code haven't helped my understanding. I would appreciate any guidance.

**Update:** For clarification, per Dan's suggestion I have tried `builder.stall_number` but it results in a

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'stall_number' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x00000102a1baf0>
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I just dealt with this today myself.

You can access the object of the fields_for through:

```
builder.object
```

where builder is your fields_for form builder object. In your particular case, you can say:

```
<p>Enter license for car parked in stall: <%= builder.object.stall_number%></p>
```

That should do it for you!

Comment: This object's reference to relations are all broken @CharlieMezak

Answer (score 3):

The way you are trying is does not work because you want to access `car` without filling that variable for data.

I guess you want to have multiple blocks of stalls, where you can enter license plates. For each stall you will need your own `fields_for`.
I would suggest something like that:

```
<%= form_for @garage do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title, "Garage Name" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <% for i in 1..5 %>
    <% f.fields_for @garage.cars[i] do |builder| %>
      <p>Enter license for car parked in stall: <%= builder.stall_number%></p>
      <%= builder.label :license, "License #:" %><br />
      <%= builder.text_field :license %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Within the fields_for you need to use the form object you define there, in this case builder. Since the data there are not mapped to the outer form (f), but to the cars object (builder).

Comment: Sorry Dan, I should have mentioned that "builder.stall_number" was the first thing that I tried, but unfortunately using it I get a:

 NoMethodError - undefined method `stall_number' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x00000102a1baf0>.  

Any thoughts on what it could mean?  Thanks!

Comment: In your controller you build the car models! Then you need to reference them aswell. Look at the code I posted. For each stall you need to have your own sub form. @garage.stalls refers to all 5 stalls, therefore Ruby doesn't know which one you want to use.
You could just try the following, use your code and substitute :cars with @garage.cars[1] and change car.stall_number to builder.stall_number