# Creating multiple nested forms using simple_form and rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm trying to create a simple app with the following models:
categories --[has_many]--> questions --[has_many]--> answers

I have the following code for creating categories + questions(categories/_form.haml.html):

```
= simple_form_for(@category) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :title, label: "Category title: "
  = f.simple_fields_for :questions, @category.questions.build do |q|
    = q.input :content, label: "Question content: "
  = f.button :submit
```

And I'm using all the same code for creating questions + answers(questions/_form.haml.html). I have all the relations, strong parameters, nested attrs and controllers configured, it works just fine for me.

Two questions:

1. How to create multiple questions in categories/_form.haml.html?
2. How to create category + multiple questions + multiple answers per each question at once(in categories/_form.haml.html)?

I've spent a few hours trying to figure out how to accomplish the second one and all the info I was able to find is related to Rails 3.0 and form_for. None of them worked for me.

The most straightforward solution here should be something like:

```
= simple_form_for(@category) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :title, label: "Category title: "
  = f.simple_fields_for :questions, @category.questions.build do |q|
    = q.input :content, label: "Question content: "
    = q.simple_fields_for :answers, q.questions.build do |a|
      = a.input :content, label: "Answer content"
  = f.button :submit
```

But it gives me

```
undefined method `questions' for #<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You got it wrong here: `= q.simple_fields_for :answers, q.questions.build do |a|`
You are calling `questions` method on builder object `q` instead of a model object.
Probably You want this:

```
= q.simple_fields_for :answers, q.object.questions.build
```

Answer (score 3):

i am not going to answer the first two questions as i think they are explained here in depth: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

i just want to give you some hints about the error. you really have to learn how to read error-messages and stacktraces if you want to become a professional.

so here is a detailed explanation of the error that states `undefined method`questions' for #

first of all, it is very important to provide complete stacktraces. that is because they include line numbers. line number are important when resolving issues.

i guess that the line in question here is `= q.simple_fields_for :answers, q.questions.build do |a|`

if you look at the message, it says that the object `q` is of type `FormBuilder`. this is the object that rails instantiates when you call `form_for` or `fields_for`. when you use SimpleForm, it's also in `simple_form_for` and `simple_fields_for`, but an extended version (most often called a decorated version).

this object `q` does not have a method `question` and never will! i assume that you want to access the underlying object that the `fields_for` method wraps. you can access this via `q.object` (see this post for more infos [Rails - Using form_for and fields_for, how do you access the sub-object while in the fields_for block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038341/rails-using-form-for-and-fields-for-how-do-you-access-the-sub-object-while-in)).

in your case i also assume a mix of `answers` versus `questions`. i think that this should be `q.simple_fields_for :answers, q.object.answers.build` instead of `q.simple_fields_for :answers, q.questions.build`.

Comment: Thanks phoet. Mix between answers and question was a copy&paste mistake. And I've found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038341/rails-using-form-for-and-fields-for-how-do-you-access-the-sub-object-while-in before but read it too quickly. I was sure I'm doing it incorrectly by trying to call "questions" or "answers" method on FromBuilder but I had no idea I could access the underlying object by just calling object method on it. Thanks for taking time for such a detailed answer. And I'm still not sure I should use railcasts episodes for Rails 3.0 since it really differs