# Calculate Price x quantity Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need your support with ruby on rails. I'm trying to calculate the result of price and quantity in the light of new and edit.En view show if it works.
I'm using Simple_form, calculate input quantity and price. automatically and must leave the result. sending the code.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@ticket) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :fecha %>
    <%= f.input :impuesto, :input_html => { value: '18.00'} %>
    <%= f.association :customer, label_method: "#{:nombre}", value_method: :id, prompt: "Debes buscar la empresa" %>
    <%= f.association :status %>
    <div>

    <table id="items">
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center" width="60px">ITEM</th>
            <th class="text-center" width="160px">CODIGO</th>
            <th class="text-center" width="225px">DESCRIPCION</th>
            <th class="text-center" width="100px">CANTIDAD</th>
            <th class="text-center" width="110px">PRECIO</th> 
            <th class="text-center" width="150px">TOTAL <%= @empresa.moneda1 %></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
    </table>    
<%= simple_nested_form_for @ticket, :wrapper => false do |g| %>
    <table id="detail_tickets">
    <%= g.simple_fields_for :detail_tickets do |p| %>
    <tr class="fields">
        <th align="center" width="60px" class="text-center"><%= p.input :item, label: false %></th>
        <th align="center" width="160px"><%= p.input :code, label: false %></th>
        <th align="center" width="225px" class="description"><%= p.input :description, label: false, :input_html => {:rows => 3} %></th>
        <th align="center" width="100px" class="text-center"><%= p.input :cantidad, label: false %></th>
        <th align="center" width="110px" class="text-right"><%= p.input :price, label: false %></th>
        <% @total_price = params[:cantidad].to_s.to_d * params[:price].to_s.to_d %> 
        <th align="right" width="150px" class="text-right"><%= @total_price %></th>
        <th align="center" width="63px" class="text-center"><%= p.link_to_remove "", class: "btn btn-danger fa fa-trash" %></th>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>

    <table id="items">
        <tr>
            <th width="700px"></th>
            <th class="text-center" width="110px">VALOR DE VENTA : </th> 
            <th class="text-center" width="150px"></th> 
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th width="700px"></th>
            <th class="text-center" width="110px">I.G.V. : </th> 
            <th class="text-center" width="150px"></th> 
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th width="700px"></th>
            <th class="text-center" width="110px">TOTAL : </th> 
            <th class="text-center" width="150px"></th> 
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p><%= g.link_to_add "Adicionar Producto", :detail_tickets, :data => { :target => "#detail_tickets" }, class: "btn btn-primary" %></p>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What error message do you get or what should your code do which its not doing?

Comment: <% @total_price = params[:cantidad].to_s.to_d * params[:price].to_s.to_d %>

Comment: do not get the parameter data.

Comment: Are you passing the parameters `:cantidad` and `:price` to the page, try printing them in console, using `<% puts "\ncantidad #{params[:cantidad]}, price: #{params[:price]} \n" %>`. May I ask why are you converting the params to string and then to big data-decimal?

Comment: cantidad , price:  

nothing comes!!!!

Comment: Processing by TicketsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3IquFKLKLbbk7w85O+FbFrqhFdDeiUjt6HK/6Kq/Lwt4nAIct6MPOUvnv1r7DBSMWnbfwGO9ew8VnjFu19ImfQ==", "ticket"=>{"fecha(3i)"=>"20", "fecha(2i)"=>"12", "fecha(1i)"=>"2015", "impuesto"=>"18.00", "customer_id"=>"69", "status_id"=>"1", "detail_tickets_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"item"=>"1", "code"=>"12", "description"=>"21321ddsd", "cantidad"=>"12", "price"=>"12", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Crear"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
cantidad , price:

Comment: Which page you have posted above in the question? Is it the page which gets rendered after the create action and from where are you getting the `price` and `cantidad` parameters?

Comment: I've posted it before creating or updating.

Comment: **<% @total_price = p.object.cantidad.to_i * p.object.price.to_i %>**. Let me know if it works. I hope [this]( http://stackoverflow.com/a/5224847) answer might help you.

Comment: Did it work for you? Because this is first time I came across this through your question.